# color the background of a text field related to the character space left

Tags: c#, textbox, background-color

Does anyone know if its possible to color the background of the field depending on the character space left?
You start with an empty field an the whole background for example is lightblue. Now as you type characters the portion of lightblue will decrease so when there's no lightblue in the background left you know that you have reached the maximum amount of characters.

I use C# as my programming language. 
I hope and very appreciate  any help.
Thanks in advance, Erik

Comment: I would simply create a new class that's derived from the original textbox and add some logic to it. You can set the background color brush with *.Background*, btw.

Comment: i don't completely understand, do you want to change the background of the entire TextBox or more like a progressbar?

Comment: yes, such effect can be created. is it wpf textbox or winforms?

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you change the background )in WPF, in winForm is the backColor):

```
textBox1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

You need also to set the MaxLenght property in the xaml (I'm supponsing you're working on wpf).

For the background only for the remaining part of the maxLenght, I think you have to custom the class of textbox and do some raw work here.

Comment: in winforms TextBox has BackColor property

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do this by javascript to avoid postback.
This example lighten the background color for the textbox as the user writes, and darken the color if any character is removed.

Markup:

```
 <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="setBoxColor(this,20);" maxlength="10"/>
```

Javascript:

```
//Define startcolor for textbox.
    var startColor = "rgb(0, 148, 255)";

    $(function () {
        $("#txt1").css("background-color", startColor);
    });

    function setBoxColor(ctrl, light)
    {
        if (ctrl.value.length == 0)
        {
            $("#" + ctrl.id).css("background-color", startColor);
            return;
        }

        var color = startColor; 
        color = color.replace(/[^0-9,]+/g, "");
        var red = color.split(",")[0];
        var gre = color.split(",")[1];
        var blu = color.split(",")[2];

        $("#" + ctrl.id).css("background-color", Lighthen(red, gre, blu, light * ctrl.value.length));
    }


    function Lighthen(red, green, blue, light) {
        var max = ([red, green, blue].sort(function (l, r) { return r - l }))[0];
        var multiplier = max;
        multiplier = (multiplier / 255) + light;
        if (multiplier < 1.5) multiplier = 1.9;

        if ((max * multiplier) > 255) {
            multiplier = (multiplier / 230) + 1;
        }

        var r = Math.round(red * multiplier);
        var g = Math.round(green * multiplier);
        var b = Math.round(blue * multiplier);

        if (r > 255) r = 255;
        if (g > 255) g = 255;
        if (b > 255) b = 255;

        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    }
```